# Reputations for Today

Tags: script, reputation

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Reputations for Today]

### About

- Caculate Reputations for Today
- Linked to Jon Skeet's Reputation Tracker
- Number in the bracket does not include accepted answers (experimental feature)

#### License

probably CC-BY-SA

#### Download

https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/97579

#### Platform

Tested only on Firefox 3.6, Google Chrome 11 dev
(Linux versions)

#### Contact

S.Mark - mark at my-mm dot org

#### Code

Userscript (Javascript) using existing stackoverflow jQuery

source - https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/97579

Comment: Closing this because of this does not work anymore because rep-graph function is gone.